# SVG animation keySplines and keyTimes not working

Tags: css, svg

I'm having trouble getting an svg animation to run using keySplines and keyTimes. If I remove the keyTimes and keySplines the animation runs just fine. If I add them back, the animation doesn't run. I'm experiencing the same issue in Chrome/Safari/Firefox so I don't think it's a browser issue.

```
<animate attributeName="d" attributeType="XML" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite" end="indefinite" 
dur="17000ms" values="M190.5,685.5l90,20l-50,60l-40-40l0,0V685.5z;M190.5,685.5l50,20l-70,50l20-30l0,0V685.5z" 
keySplines="0.5, 0, 0.5, 1; 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1" keyTimes="0; 1" calcMode="spline"></animate>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There must be one fewer sets of [keysplines](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#KeySplinesAttribute) control points than there are ‘keyTimes’

If there are any errors in the ‘keySplines’ specification (bad values, too many or too few values), the document fragment is in error.

You have the same number so that's what happens.

Comment: Thanks Robert, that was it. I had one too many sets of keySplines. Changing it to have only one set of keySplines fixed my issue.